# Creating a datatable with a many-to-many relationship from several datatables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope my question makes sense firstly.

So I have several csv files that I want to merge into one DataFrame, each of these DataFrames is structured similarly, with a certain metric being recorded on an object per year. Each DataFrame is separated by a certain category.

For example, a simplified version is student grades per class:

```
DF1: Math

Year . Student1 . Student2  ... Student500 . Student501

2001 .   90     .    84     ...     92     .     65

2002 .   84     .    62     ...     70     .    100

...

2020 .   75     .    43     ...     50      .    83




DF2: Science

Year . Student1 . Student2  ... Student500 . Student501

2001 .   56     .    70     ...     82     .     99

2002 .   76     .    55     ...     70     .     80

...

2020 .   75     .    43     ...     50      .    83



DF3: History

Year . Student1 . Student2  ... Student500 . Student501

2001 .   90     .    84     ...     92     .     65

2002 .   84     .    62     ...     70     .    100

...

2020 .   75     .    43     ...     50      .    83
```

I am looking to combine these DataFrames into one Data Frame that has the following structure

```
Year  .  Student  .  Math  .  Science  . English
```

My attempt has been to create a new empty DataFrame like so:

```
import pandas as pd
combinedDf = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[], 'Student':[], 'Math':[], 'Science':[], 'English':[]})
```

and to then try to manually iterate on each data frame, looping through each row and appending the data to the combinedDf. So with the Math table I would have to add None and None for the Science and English values, until I iterate on those values in the relevant dataframes so that I could insert them in my combinedDf. This quickly became quite frustrating to handle as sometimes a year or a student was missing from one of the tables.

So my question is: is there an easier way to merge these DataFrames? I imagine it shouldn't be this complicated, but I can't seem to find a simpler way to go about it.

Thanks

Comment: So you say `df1` is `math`, `df2` is `science`, how do you indicate this? Is this a given?

Comment: I hope this points you in the right direction . pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file).assign(course = 'filename')] . I assume the csvs are labelled 'math','science', bla bla bla. The list comprehension reads in each file and creates a new column for course name. concat function combines them into one. from there you can do some manipulation to get what you want. alternatively, you can read the data in using python's csv module as a dictionary and align the data from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `concat` with `stack`

```
s=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],keys=['math','scie','his']).\
      set_index('Year',append=True).stack().unstack(level=0).reset_index()
```